# Chrome: can you evaluate, using Javascript, an XPath that points to an element on a different URL than the current page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, applescript, cross-domain

You can use something like this to emulate a click in Javascript:

```
document.evaluate("/html/body/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button", document.body, null, 9, null). singleNodeValue.click();
```

**I would like to send such a click to an element that is on another URL than the currently displayed page**, a "special URL" - the URL of an extension (e.g., chrome-extension://bkdgflcldnnnapblkhphbgpggdiikppg/dashboard/html/browser.html).

The context is Applescript - I am scripting Chrome to do something. Chrome's Applescript supports `execute javascript` which allows you to send a JS to be executed by Chrome's JS-engine. Some pseudo-Applescript-code of how it may look:

```
tell Chrome to load URL "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
    execute javascript "document.evaluate("chrome-extension://bkdgflcldnnnapblkhphbgpggdiikppg/dashboard/html/browser.html/html/body/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button", document.body, null, 9, null). singleNodeValue.click();"
end tell
```

Note the pseudo-XPath in the `document.evaluate`.

Can this be done?

Comment: I doubt you can do it in the XPath. You'd need to get a reference to the other document, e.g. if it's in an iframe you'd use `document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.document.evaluate(...)`

Comment: This also assumes that the iframe is in the same domain, so you can access its contents.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think it is an iframe, it is one of those windows that opens when you click on most of your browser extensions, some kind of drop-down window from the browser toolbar. Note the URL I provided.

Comment: Structurally it's similar, it's a separate browser object. Since it's not directly related to the current window, I don't think there's way to address it.

Comment: You need to find some way to access the window and then its document or directly the document showing e.g. `chrome-extension://bkdgflcldnnnapblkhphbgpggdiikppg/dashboard/html/browser.html`, then you can probably just use `evaluate(/html/body/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button", document.body, null, 9, null). singleNodeValue.click();` on that document.